# Recorrido hacia la izquierda de array en Java

Tags: java, array

Tengo que hacer un programa en el que
1.Tengo un array de 5 elementos
2.Lleno el array de forma automática con ciclo for con los números del 0 al 4
3.Defino un numero aleatorio hasta 5 con security.SecureRandom
El objetivo es que el numero arrojado con SecureRandom indique la posición del arreglo que va a ser reemplazado con el primer elemento del arreglo.
Es decir si el vector es v = {0,1,2,3,4} y el numero aleatorio arrojado es 3, el valor del índice 3 debe ser reemplazado con el valor del índice 0, los valores antes de la posición 3 deben moverse a la derecha y los valores después moverse a la izquierda, al final el vector debe quedar como: V = {1,2,3,0,4}.

EL OBJETIVO PRINCIPAL ES INTERCAMBIAR LAS POSICIONES DE LOS NUMEROS COMO SI BARAJARA CARTAS(en este caso barajar números)
*******Lo que yo hice*******
Bueno en realidad esta es la simplificacion de un problema mas grande en el que son 52 elementos del array, pero estoy trabajando en el problema pequeño para entender mejor.

Lo que hice fue usar un ciclo for de esta forma:

```
for (int k = 0; k < numeros.length; k++) {
        int j = cartaAleatoria.nextInt(5);
        int temp = numeros[0];


        for(int i = 1; i < j; i++) {

            numeros[i-1] = numeros[i];
        }
        numeros[j] = temp;

    }
```

Pero como en el ciclo el valor de temp va a variar ya que al desplazarse el valor de la posicion 1 a la posicion 0 temp no sería el valor original del vector que estaba al inicio y ahi está mi problema. adjunto el código completo

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
public class AppBaraja {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Carta cr1 = new Carta("tres", "treboles");
        System.out.println(cr1.toString());

        SecureRandom cartaAleatoria = new SecureRandom();
        //PRUEBA

        int[] numeros = new int[5];

        //Llenado del vector
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {

            numeros[i] = i;
        }

        //Impresion del vector
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {

            System.out.printf("%5d", numeros[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("\nPrueba ");
        for (int k = 0; k < numeros.length; k++) {
            int j = cartaAleatoria.nextInt(5);
            int temp = numeros[0];


            for(int i = 1; i < j; i++) {

                numeros[i-1] = numeros[i];
            }
            numeros[j] = temp;

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {

            System.out.printf("%5d", numeros[i]);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución es que uses memoria adicional, para crear otro array con las posiciones finales, y usar el anterior como referencia para saber que número va en que posición.

En mi siguiente código esta un método que recibe el array original `nums` y un número `k`, que son las posiciones que se moverá el array.

Así que recorremos el array original, y calculamos de acuerdo al indice actual, en dónde quedaría ese elemento. Para ello solo le sumamos al indice actual, el número de posiciones que debe moverse y le sacamos el modulo respecto al tamaño del array`(i + k) % size`.

```
public void rotate(int[] nums, int k) {
    int size = nums.length;
    int[] res = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        int newIndex = (i + k) % size;
        res[newIndex] = nums[i];
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        nums[i] = res[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías ir rotando el array,almacenando los valores consecutivos y solo cuando el indice sea igual al `indiceAletorio`  usar `break;` para detener la rotación y el almacenamiento

```
int j = cartaAleatoria.nextInt(5);
int temp=numeros[0]; //se almacena el primer valor del array
        int l=0;//el indice que recorrera el array
        for (int k = 1; k <= numeros.length; k++) {                    
           if(l==j){//solo cuando el indice de recorrido sea igual al indice aleatorio,guardaremos el primer valor del array obtenido en el indiceAleatorio
             numeros[j]=temp;
             break;
           }else{
             numeros[l]=numeros[k];
             l++;
           }
        }
```

siendo el array 0 1 2 3 4

```
    //3    12304
    //2    12034
    //4    12340
    //1    10234
```